# How to delete a User at RabbitMQ using Python

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I have written that code but queue is not deleted:

```
import pika
import time
import json
import datetime

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_delete(queue='hello')
```

I can delete queue name. but how can I delete user

Comment: This manual has an example and also some potential pitfalls: https://blog.serverdensity.com/clearing-purging-rabbitmq-queues/

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following command:

```py
import os
os.system("rabbitmqctl delete_user my_user")
```

Here complete documentation: https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmqctl.8.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete users then you need to access the Management HTTP API from Python. See https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html

Although perhaps you don't want to do that directly from Python and prefer to use something like the **rabbitmqadmin** mentioned there https://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html